# How to create a custom-element "resize" mixin for Polymer 2?

Tags: ecmascript-6, polymer, mixins, web-component, custom-element

I'm trying to upgrade a Polymer 1.8 component to Polymer 2.

As explained in the documentation, `behaviors` are replaces by class mixin, but I'm not really confident with theses. After some search, about how to replace the `iron-resizable-behavior`, I'm not able to find how to build it.

Is there someone to show me where I can find some documentation on it or/and explain how can I design mixins to react on events?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Hybrid Behavior

In the [`2.0-preview` branch of `<iron-resizable-behavior>`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-resizable-behavior/blob/2.0-preview/iron-resizable-behavior.html), `Polymer.IronResizableBehavior` is a *hybrid behavior* (i.e., defined as an object instead of a class mixin). Polymer 2 provides [`Polymer.mixinBehaviors()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#using-hybrid-behaviors-with-class-style-elements) to merge one or more hybrid mixins with a class.

*Usage:*

```
class NEW_CLASSNAME extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors(HYBRID_MIXINS_ARRAY, SUPERCLASSNAME) { ... }
```

*Example:*

```
class MyView1 extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors([Polymer.IronResizableBehavior], Polymer.Element) {
  static get is() { return 'my-view1'; }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.addEventListener('iron-resize', this._logResizeEvent);
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    super.disconnectedCallback();
    this.removeEventListener('iron-resize', this._logResizeEvent);
  }

  _logResizeEvent(e) {
    console.debug('resize', e);
  }
}

window.customElements.define(MyView1.is, MyView1);
```

#### Behavior-Class Mixin

You could [create a *behavior-class mixin*](http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/) like this:

```
const MyMixin = (superclass) => class extends superclass {  
  foo() {
    console.log('foo from MyMixin');
  }
};
```

Then, you'd use it in your Polymer element like this:

```
class MyView1 extends MyMixin(Polmer.Element) {
  onClick() {
    this.foo(); // <-- from MyMixin
  }
}
```

#### Hybrid Behavior + Behavior-Class Mixin

You could use *hybrid behaviors* and *behavior-class mixins* together like this:

```
class MyView1 extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors([Polymer.IronResizableBehavior], MyMixin(Polmer.Element)) {
  onClick() {
    this.foo();                               // <-- from MyMixin
    console.log(this._interestedResizables);  // <-- from Polymer.IronResizableBehavior
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#mixins), you only need to do the following:

Change:

```
class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
  // Implementation
}
```

To:

```
class MyElement extends Polymer.IronResizableBehavior(Polymer.Element) {
  // Implementation
}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: No, I've tried it but I have an error `Polymer.IronResizableBehavior is not a function`. When I'm looking at the code of the behavior, it's not class-based, as tony19 says.

Comment: Then you will probably need to use the `Polymer.mixinBehaviors` until the `Polymer.IronResizableBehavior` is not rewritten as a class behavior.

Comment: Yes, It's what I've done and it's working now. I've missed the line saying that behaviors has designed using hybrid mode. thanks